# Why can we not combine all the constructors, why must there be three overloaded constructors in typical inheritance cases?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class CircleGeometricObject extends GeometricObject  {

    private double radius;

    public CircleGeometricObject() {}
    public CircleGeometricObject(double radius) {
        this. radius = radius;
    }
    public CircleGeometricObject(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
        this. radius = radius;
        setColor(color);
        setFilled( filled);
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on your requirement.

Comment: :) what does "13 String color" mean here?

Comment: Consider putting some effort into formatting your code well before posting. We greatly appreciate your efforts here.

Comment: Please state what exactly is bothering you and what you would prefer.

Comment: I would rather have one constructor, for example, something similar to this :public CircleGeometricObject( double radius, 13 String color, boolean filled)

{

                                           this. radius = radius;
                                           setColor( color);
                                           setFilled( filled);
}

Comment: Basically, why can we not get rid of the first two constructors ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think you need the first two constructors? What happens without them?

Comment: I appreciate your help cyroxx.

Comment: The only reason you need all 3 is if you might want them.  If GeometricObject defines the `()` or `(double)` constructor but you don't in the subclass then there's no default version created for the subclass.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to reduce code duplication you could do something like below (add some null checking though). It's possibly over the top for your example, but for constructors with lots of code it can be useful to reduce duplication.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Double radius;

    public MyClass() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public class MyClass(Double radius) {
        this(radius, null, null)
    }

    public class MyClass(Double radius, String colour, boolean filled) {
        this.radius = radius;
        setColour(colour);
        setFilled(filled);
    }
}
```

** edited to change double to Double to allow null

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to correclty understand the question. Do you ask why you have to *override* the constructor of GeometricObject ?

It is not mandatory the following code compile :

```
public class CircleGeometricObject extends GeometricObject
{
private double radius;

public CircleGeometricObject(double radius, String color, boolean filled)
{
    this.radius = radius;
    setColor(color);
    setFilled(filled);
}
}
```

You implement the constructors that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Had to create a testcase, since it's been so long, and this was always a sort of fuzzy area:

```
public class ConstrTest {
    protected String fieldA;
    protected String fieldB;
    public static void main(String[] argV) {
        ConstrTestSub sub1 = new ConstrTestSub("111", "222");
        sub1.print();
        // ConstrTestSub sub2 = new ConstrTestSub();
        // sub2.print();
    }
    public ConstrTest() {
        this("ABC","XYZ");
    }
    public ConstrTest(String a) {
        this(a, "YYY");
    }
    public ConstrTest(String a, String b) {
        fieldA = a;
        fieldB = b;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("fieldA = " + fieldA + ", fieldB = " + fieldB);
    }
}

class ConstrTestSub extends ConstrTest {
    private String fieldC;
    public ConstrTestSub(String a, String b) {
        super(a, b);
        fieldC = "QQQ";
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("fieldA = " + fieldA + ", fieldB = " + fieldB + ", fieldC = " + fieldC);
    }
}
```

The above code compiles and runs fine, and the ConstTestSub constructor executes the corresponding `super` version appropriately (which it would do even without the explicit `super` invocation).

If you uncomment the second `new ConstTestSub` in main, though, it will not compile, since the `()` version of the constructor is not defined.

So, ***if*** you're going to define your constructors at all, and ***if*** you need multiple forms, you must define all the forms you need.  (They can, of course, just be cascaded if that's sufficient.)